# Select an item out of a combo box with a vbscript

Tags: vbscript, combobox, qtp

I am writing a few tests in vbscript for an application that I am working on, and I need to select one option out of several in a combo box. Does anyone know how to do this? The way I am currently "selecting" the option is

```
Browser("main_browser").Page("main_page").WebEdit("teams").Set "Thunder"
```

This will make this field equal to "Thunder", but the application does not recognize this as the "Thunder" choice in my combobox, merely a string with the value "Thunder" that has been injected, so to speak.

By the way, I am using quick test pro as an environment.

Comment: you can use  index of option value to set in drop down

Comment: Try recording the selection, and look at the code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the *combo box* is a real combo box (a `SELECT` HTML tag)?

When QTP sees a `select` tag it identifies it as a `WebList` and not as a `WebEdit` as you listed. Then you can perform `WebList.Select` which does a native selection (and not `Set`). It could be that you don't have a read HTML combo-box, instead you have an edit-box that simulates a combo-box and then `.Set` just sets the text.

If you are unable to recognise the control as a `WebEdit` you will have to examine the HTML to see what event causes the selection of the field to change and use `WebEdit.FireEvent` in order to simulate a human's interaction.